# Permission denied to homebrew trying to acces /tmp

Tags: unix, permissions, homebrew, tmp

**PROBLEM SOLVED, SEE BOTTOM OF POST FOR SOLUTION**

I'm having issues with homebrew and persmissions. Some brew commands try accessing `/tmp`, which it doesn't have permissions for. For example, I try running brew doctor:

```
$ brew doctor
Error: Permission denied - /tmp/doctor20150702-2168-1se1w8u
```

I have a suspicion that the problem was introduced when I installed brew-rmtree, but I am not sure. A similar thing happens when I try to install rmtree:

```
$ brew install brew-rmtree
==> Installing brew-rmtree from beeftornado/homebrew-rmtree
Error: Permission denied - /tmp/homebrew20150702-516-1b1s5b3
```

This is the only package installation that causes this problem.

I don't have the slightest idea why brew tries to access `/tmp`, since brew is supposed to write only to `usr/local`. My `/tmp` folder is of course owned by root:

```
$ ls / | grep /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel    11B Apr 12 00:57 tmp@ -> private/tmp
```

Running `brew doctor` is my go to solution, but now that fails as well, and I am dumbfounded. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

It turns out that the issue with homebrew was merely a symptom, not the problem itself. `/tmp` is a symlink, `tmp@ -> private/tmp`, and something was up with my permissions at `/private/tmp` (still don't know what, never figured it out).

So I ran disk permission reparation  by opening Disk Utility, selecting my drive partition and running Repair Disk Permission. One of the first paths that it reported having repaired was `/private/tmp`, and after that it has worked fine.

This wasn't exactly a homebrew problem, then.

Comment: whats the output of `echo $HOMEBREW_TEMP`?

Comment: The problem is solved, see edit. (FYI: HOMEBREW_TEMP was unset).